# Extracting Mp4 files from multiple folders into one folder

Tags: copy, extract

I currently have like 100s of folders containing mp4 files in my /Downloads folder

How can I move all the mp4 from the subfolders into 1 folder at once?
Also the subfolders names are all diffrent the only thing they have in common is that they contain mp4 files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming every single .mp4 file has a unique filename, you can do something like this:

```
find ~/Downloads -type f -iname "*.mp4" -exec cp -av "{}" /path/to/destination/ \;
```

This will find all .mp4 files in your Downloads folder and copy them to a single folder.

If you really want to, you can replace `cp -av` with `mv -v`. This will move the files to a new destination instead of copying them.

Comment: Another error:./Downloads/I win today.mp4' -> '/videos1/'
cp: cannot create regular file '/videos1/': Not a directory

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash script will do it for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
# A script to move files to a directory from all found under the working directory.
for i in $(find "$PWD" -type f | grep .mp4 ); do
    # Name of file to use in output file for further prosessing
    NAME=$(basename "$i") 
    # Directory of the file to be moved.
    DIR=$(dirname "$i")
    # move the file to the directory passed in on the command line located in the current working directory.
    mv "$DIR/$NAME" "$PWD/$1"      
done
```

From my video processing script I have I never allow any illegal characters or spaces in my files. If you have them hopefully the "" work. Put an echo "$DIR/$NAME" for that line off the start to confirm it will do as expected and give the full path of the files. I am experimenting on my audio files in a temp directory with the script. It is good idea to give it a try on duplicates of your own. The script takes the directory to move into in the working directory. This would be the top level directory where your files are all located it will search for all .mp4 files under this and move them in the directory in this top level you want all the singles files in. I have copy of the script of mine in this top level directory I was testing on.

```
MacUser2525:/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special$ ./test_move.sh
snip ....
/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special/38_Special_1991_Bone_Against_Steel/38_Special-Bone_Against_Steel-13-Treasure.m4a
```

It showed the proper name and path so onto testing the actual move. Now the files to move the amount of them.

```
MacUser2525:/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special$ find . -type file | grep .m4a  | wc -l
      69
```

The target directory.

```
MacUser2525:/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special$ find test -type file | grep .m4a  | wc -l
       0
```

The command run with the -v command for the moving to show what it does.

```
MacUser2525:/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special$ test_move.sh test
snip ....
/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special/38_Special_1991_Bone_Against_Steel/38_Special-Bone_Against_Steel-13-Treasure.m4a -> /Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special/test/38_Special-Bone_Against_Steel-13-Treasure.m4a
```

The target directory after the moving.

```
MacUser2525:/Volumes/Sea_To_Do/working/38_Special$ find test -type file | grep .m4a  | wc -l
      69
```

Success I moved all 69 files from their different directories to the single directory destination. It should do the same for you, without any funky naming, guaranteed like it just did for me. Spaces and junk like that in the file names no clue. I think the "" will do it but I never work with files like that.